# User edit page not working

Tags: codeigniter

When i click on my user edit button `<?php echo anchor('users/edit/'. $user->user_id, '<div class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</div>');?>`

It sends me to `http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-blog/admin/users/edit/1` but shows error 404 Page Not Found. **'1' example is the user_id**

But edit function exists. How can I make my edit function on my users controller work with the user id. So if i click on a certain user it will only update that id row information.

***Model***

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_user extends CI_Model {

    protected $id;

    function getAll() {
        $query = $this->db->get('user');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            return $query->result();
            return $query->row('user_id');
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function editUser() {

    }

    public function getID($user_id) {
           $user_query = $this->db->get('user');

            if ($user_query->num_rows() == 1) {

                  return  $user_query->row('user_id', $user_id);

                  return true;

            } else {

                  return false;

            }
      }
}
```

***Controller***

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('user');

        if ($this->session->userdata('isLogged') == TRUE) {

            return true;

        } else {

            redirect('/');

        }
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->getList();
    }

    public function edit() {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->load->model('users/model_user');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            redirect('users');

        } else {

            $this->getForm();   
        }

    }

    function getForm() {
        $data['title'] = "Users";

        $data['base'] = config_item('HTTP_SERVER');

        $data['isLogged'] = $this->user->isLogged();

        $this->load->model('users/model_user');

        $data['users'] = $this->model_user->getAll();

        $data['header'] = $this->load->view('template/common/header', $data, TRUE);
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

        return $this->load->view('template/users/users_form', $data);
    }

    function getList() {
        $data['title'] = "Users";

        $data['base'] = config_item('HTTP_SERVER');

        $data['isLogged'] = $this->user->isLogged();

        $this->load->model('users/model_user');

        $data['text_enabled'] = "Enabled";
        $data['text_disabled'] = "Disabled";

        $data['users'] = $this->model_user->getAll();

        $data['header'] = $this->load->view('template/common/header', $data, TRUE);
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('template/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

        return $this->load->view('template/users/users_list', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your base url in the config? Anchor functions build up the url with the base_url, probably it's setted to "..admin/" in this case you should put your controller inside an admin folder in the controllers.

Comment: Base controllers all the same every thing works fine but not working when have user_id on end after `edit/` its something in edit function I think.

Answer (score 0):

May be you miss to use **index.php** in url

(OR)

Use below code **base_url('');**

```
<?php 
$url=base_url('users/edit/'. $user->user_id);
echo anchor($url, '<div class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</div>');?>
```

Comment: No does not work same issue. my edit function does not allow me to view my form when have user_id on end of uri.

Comment: I can view page http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-blog/admin/users/edit/ with out user id at end fine but when click on user edit button need to make sure I can only update that user and show there profile.

Answer (score 0):

I can view page now to do with routes `$route['users/edit/(:num)'] = "users/users/edit/$1";`